# Unable to delete cookie in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, cookies

i have a series of functions that Set/Get and load cookies
for now i use them to save some Sign Up info about a form witch includes Username Email Age and Birthdate
and it works fine i can set the cookie read it and also load it in the section i want
after this i tried to use cookie for storing other data and it didnt worked out so now i want to delete it
the cookie is named CalcHistory
note that i have access to this cookie and i can get it using my GetCookie function but i can not delete it
here is the code
i looked into bunch of topics here and asked the ChatGPT a lot of times but it did not solved my case

```
// DeleteCookie function witch gets its value from an input but i aslo tried handing value manually 
// and it did not work
function DeleteCookie(cookieName) {
  document.cookie = cookieName + "=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/; SameSite=Strict";
  console.log(document.cookie)
}

// SetCookie Function
function SetCookie(name, value, expire) {
  let Name = name.toString();
  let Value = value.toString();
  var currentDate = new Date().getTime();
  var ExpirationDate = new Date(currentDate + (expire * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)).toString();
  document.cookie = Name + "=" + Value + ";" + "expires=" + ExpirationDate +  ";" + "path=/" + ";" + "SameSite=Strict" + ";";
}

// GetCookie Function
function GetCookie(CookieName){
  let Name = CookieName + "=";
  let CookieArray = document.cookie.split(";");
  for(n in CookieArray){
    let Cookies = CookieArray[n].trim();
    if (Cookies.indexOf(Name) == 0){
      return Cookies.substring(Name.length);
    }
  }  
  return null;
}

//Self Invoking function so my account info data loads up on page reload 
(function CookieLoader(){
  let UserName = GetCookie("UserName");
  let UserAge = GetCookie("UserAge");
  let UserEmail = GetCookie("UserEmail");
  let UserBirthDate = GetCookie("UserBirthDate");
  document.getElementById("account-info").innerHTML = 
  "Username : " + UserName + "<br>" +
  "Age : " + UserAge + "<br>" +
  "Email : " + UserEmail + "<br>" +
  "BirthDay : " + UserBirthDate + "<br>" ;
})()
```

i tried asking question from chatGPT and looking into few topics in stackoverflow

Comment: and i fotgot to point out when i try to Delete it in the console with DeleteCookie("CalcHistory") it gives me undefined

Comment: Click on the `Edit` button to add details to the question.

Comment: The function doesn't return anything, `undefined` is the default return value.

Comment: yes i see but i still can not remove the cookie i also tried using different approch like this = function DeleteCookie(name){ SetCookie(name,null,null)} as i seen in Bro Code YT but it does not work cant think of any other reason

Comment: I was just addressing your point "it gives me undefined". That's normal when a function doesn't return something.

Comment: I just tested your code and DeleteCookie worked. `GetCookie()` has a problem, see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea?lq=1

Comment: somehow the code works now without changing anything changing browser or clearing catch and website data :))